# hdd won't mount

Tags: mount, hard-drive

when plug in hdd this message came up

```
 /dev/sdb1 at /media/filip/f28823a2-4de1-44c5-90fe-62fb3c241b73: Command-line   `mount -t "ext4" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid" "/dev/sdb1" "/media/filip/f28823a2-4de1-44c5-90fe-62fb3c241b73"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1,
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error
   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail  or so
```

and this is dmesg | tail output:

```
[11870.811559] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 28 00 00 00
[11870.814268] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[11870.814283] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[11870.825302] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[11870.825318] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[11870.878658]  sdb: sdb1 sdb2
[11870.884220] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[11870.884235] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[11870.884244] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[11871.387003] EXT4-fs (sdb1): bad geometry: block count 121048832 exceeds size of device (1695488 blocks)
```

fdisk -l output:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0003bff7
```

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

```
/dev/sdb1   *        2048    13565951     6781952   83  Linux
/dev/sdb2        13565952    15663103     1048576   83  Linux
```

I apologize in advance if some crucial info is missing. I kindly ask for you to tell me which info is needed and I will post it in no time. 
Will be most grateful if someone can guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something strange has happened to this drive, but resizefs may be your saviour!
Have a look at this post: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/cannot-mount-hard-disk-block-count-exceeds-size-of-device-bad-partition-table-880149/

Comment: Jake, thank you for puting effort in answering me. I have had found thread that your link points to but never actually scrolled to the end, omg. That resize2fs tool indeed solved my problem.
Now I can proceed to my bigger issue, that is try to recover lost data/recovery partition tables with testdisk.
I will open new thread and put link here if someone had experience in solving this issue.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/482525/partitions-cant-be-recovered-disk-is-to-small-can-i-get-my-data